# Need help optimizing my code f# (creating a array of tuples)

Tags: list, optimization, recursion, f#, tuples

I need help optimizing this code, it takes 12 seconds and I need it to take around 4seconds.

```
let publication idx (lst: string [] list) = // returns a specific value of the string [] list
    lst
    |>Array.map (fun arr -> arr.[idx])


let rec Tuple (x:int) (ID:string list) (Information:string [] list) =
 if x < ID.Length then  
      let muro =  [|(ID.[x], Information|> List.filter (fun elem -> elem.[1] = humanID.[x] )|> publication 0   |> List.toArray )|]
      let rest = Tuple (x+1) ID Information
      Array.append muro rest     
 else  [||] 
let FinalTuple= Tuple 0 ID Information
```

finalTuple is a : `(string*string []) []`

the recursion is taking to much time to finish and I cant seem to make it faster (ID.Length is 1600)

thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you converting the list to an array and back?  That's wasting a great deal of time.

Comment: fixed that, It doesnt make a difference

Comment: You're still doing it in `publication`

Comment: fixed that again, I did that cause someone told me some days ago that is was faster to map on arrays than on lists (still dosent make a difrrence)

Comment: Sure, but its _not_ faster to convert to an array, map and then convert back to a list.

Comment: Try to avoid `Array.append` if you can - it is very slow.

Comment: If your recursion is deep, `Array.append` will be a bottleneck because you have to allocate a whole new block of memory for each allocation.  Also, if you make your function tail-recursive you could potentially get a large speedup since you won't have to allocate a new stack frame for each level of recursion.

Comment: I tried investigating about tail recursive functions but I wasnt able to make it work in my code, would you mind helping me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @mydogisbox's general point - going back and forth from array to list is not going to help much performance wise.
That being said, the first problem I had was, I had to dig a bit to just figure out what the code was doing - so I took the liberty to make a first rewrite, just to see if I understood what was going on:

```
let extract1 (ids:string[]) (info:string[][]) =
    [|
        for id in ids ->
            (id, [| for record in info do if record.[1] = id then yield record.[0] |])
    |]
```

My sense, reading your code, was this: given an array of "records" - arrays containing something of interest (probably a publication?) in field 0 and the author in field 1, the goal was for a given set of author ids, to extract their publications. Or something like that.

Now this is not very pretty. Also, I don't know if this is any good, so let's do a benchmark - a dataset of 1,000,000 records that look like what I think you have:

```
let ids = [| 1 .. 100 |] |> Array.map string 
let rng = System.Random()
let dataset = 
    [| for i in 0 .. 1000000 -> 
        [| System.Guid.NewGuid() |> string; rng.Next(0,100) |> string |] |]
```

Running this in FSI gives me:

```
> extract1 ids dataset |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.486, CPU: 00:00:01.484, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
val it : unit = ()
```

Can we make it prettier, or more functional-ish? Let's try:

```
let extract2 (ids:string[]) (info:string[][]) =
    ids 
    |> Seq.map (fun id -> 
        id,
        info 
        |> Seq.filter (fun record -> record.[1] = id)
        |> Seq.map (fun record -> record.[0])
        |> Seq.toArray)
    |> Seq.toArray
```

The verdict?

```
> extract2 ids dataset |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.588, CPU: 00:00:01.593, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
val it : unit = ()
```

Prettier, but not better. Maybe the issue is that we are doing multiple passes, one per id. Sounds like maybe we should group?

```
let extract3 (ids:string[]) (info:string[][]) =
    let IDs = ids |> Set.ofArray
    info
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.[1])
    |> Seq.filter (fun (id,rows) -> IDs |> Set.contains id)
    |> Seq.map (fun (id,rows) -> id, rows |> Seq.toArray)
    |> Seq.toArray

> extract3 ids dataset |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:00.387, CPU: 00:00:00.390, GC gen0: 8, gen1: 8, gen2: 0
val it : unit = ()
```

Now we are talking. I am sure we could squeeze more - feel free to go at it. The main point, though, is that the code is also simpler (IMO), and conveys more clearly what the intent is. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

When trying to improve the performance of a piece of code, the first thing to do is eliminate unneeded memory allocations.  A few places you can improve this:

1. Mapping over an array is faster than mapping over a list, but not
   faster than converting to an array, mapping and then converting back
   to a list.
2. Avoid using `Array.append`.  This results in doing a new memory allocation each time.  Instead, you might consider a `ResizeArray` or a list, where appending is much less expensive.
3. Try to make your function tail-recursive.  In your case, this means you need to pass the intermediary result into the next level of recursing.  In your case (if I understand it correctly), this would mean passing `muro` down the call chain, and then adding the result of that call to `muro` before passing it to the next recursion.

The tail-recursive function would look something like this:

```
let rec Tuple (x:int) (ID:string list) (Information:string [] list) (result:*correct type here*) =
    if x < ID.Length then  
        let muro =  [|(ID.[x], Information|> List.filter (fun elem -> elem.[1] = humanID.[x] )|> publication 0   |> List.toArray )|]
        Tuple (x+1) ID Information Array.append muro rest     
    else  result
let FinalTuple= Tuple 0 ID Information [||]
```

This probably changes the order of the resulting array, so depending on what you need you may need to rework it a bit.

Comment: would you mind helping me construct the tail recursive function. Been trying for some days and cant :(

Comment: I added a partial rework which should be enough to get you to the right answer.  Its untested so you may need to fix some compile errors.

Comment: I fixed the comple errors and the order of the resulting array but it still taking 12 seconds to solve :( im screwed

Comment: My tail-recursive suggestion doesn't eliminate the `Array.append`.  I suggest making it into a list and then prepending onto it.  That should cut down on memory allocations by a lot.

Comment: Now I am kind of curious to see if I can actually write a faster tail recursive version :)

Comment: @Mathias Heh.  You did what I was too lazy to do today.